# using Identical Comparison Operator (===) in if statement fails if not used alone?

Tags: php, comparison, conditional-operator

I want to test if a var is Identical (type and value) to one of three possibilities.

So I do:

```
if(($var === 0) || ($var === '0') || ($var === 'false'))
    // do something
```

But this results in the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function  () in /htdocs/thefile.php on line xxx

If instead, I simply use Equal Comparison operators like this:

```
if(($var == 0) || ($var == '0') || ($var == 'false'))
    // do something
```

No error is thrown, but this is not the comparison check I want to make..

Now, if I just try with one Identical comparison it goes fine:

```
if(($var === 0))
    // do something.. this throws no error :)
```

No error is thrown..

So what am I missing here...
Why does the first line not work, and what would be the correct way of doing what I'm after here?

Comment: This works for me...  Could you provide the surrounding lines of code? Is this definitely the line where the error is?

Comment: This might be a bug. Show the complete script, name PHP version and plattform. Otherwise not diagnosable with just `// do something`.

Comment: OMG, sorry girls/guys feeling like a fool here.. a hard-space had sneaked its way in instead of a normal space, I ran a test on all the invisible characters.. now it works fine (with or without the extra braces.. but you're right they were redundant, so they are gone now, thanks :) ), ..sorry about that.

Comment: +1 honest explanation of that mystery

Answer (score 1):

The `===` operator checks the *type* of the variable as well...

This should be sufficient:

```
if (!$var) {}
```

Comment: !$var will be TRUE if $var is bool(false) which I do not want. I want it to be true only if $var is string('false'). For that reason I can't use if(!$var).

Comment: @mikkelbreum: +1 thanks for that, re-reading your question I think I completely muddled what you were hoping to achieve in my mind. :-/

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
          $x=10;
          $y="10";
 echo ($x==$y);
 echo ($x===$y);
 ?>
```

Here are the o/p: bool(ture), bool(false).
   because here "10" is considered as string.
   In Identical operator it not only checks the value but also the data type.So here we are 
   comparing string with integer data type. so it results false.